# Anguarl UI-Router with basic server file issues

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am working on a “simple” website to help brush up on some skills.  I haven’t used the MEAN stack in well over a year, and it seems I am a bit rusty with the Node/Express portion in conjunction with the Angular framework.  I was told to try out the UI-Router because it would help with the main goal of my project in being able to reuse a product “template” for about 15 of the URLs since my page will be filled in with property values from a JSON file which contains the product info, such as name, description, image, etc.

I am only using nodemon to serve up my server.js file but when I go to localhost:9000 the source tab in dev-tools does not show the full file tree.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my setup:

NODE/EXPRESS
server.js

```
// set up 
var express         = require('express');
var app             = express();
var port            = process.env.PORT || 9000;
var apiRoutes       = require('./app/routes.js');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static('/node_modules'));
// routes 
app.use('/', apiRoutes);
// launch 
app.listen(port);
```

apiRoutes.js

```
var apiRouter = require('express').Router();
var express = require('express');
apiRouter.get('/', function (req, res, next){
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: './public/html'})
});
// Exports
module.exports = apiRouter;
```

ANGULAR
app.js

```
angular.module(‘myApp’,['ui.router','ngResource']);
```

app_routes.js

```
angular.module(‘myApp’)
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url : '/',
    templateUrl : '/index.html',
    controller  : 'controller_index'
  })
  .state('product', {
    url : '/:id',
    templateUrl : '/template_product.html',
    controller  : 'controller_prods'
  });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
}]);`
```

shell.html (contains my nav & footer with specific URL views inside)

```
<html ng-app=“myApp”>
<body ng-controller="controller_shell">
  <Nav goes here>
  </nav>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
```

index.html (loads the content inside  on the main URL www.myapp.com)

```
<main>
  <div> all the stuff </div>
</main>
```

template_product.html (dynamically loads the content inside  on the shell)

```
<main>
  <div> all the stuff </div>
</main>
```

I am not familiar enough with Grunt to make a build process, so I currently have `nodemon server.js` running & serving. Right now, when i go to localhost:9000 it only loads the content of index.html, but doesn’t load all the scripts/css/dependencies from shell.html

Comment: first of all, index.html should be the "default" page that the server loads when a page isn't specified, so it's not a good idea to give one of your views that name.  instead, the contents of shell.html should be what is in the index.html, and the view should be something else (main.html, home.html, or something else).

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your server file :

You launching a server instance on port 9000, that is the first point.

After that, you are telling the server that for any route starting with '/', it should use the router apiRoutes.

```
app.use('/', apiRoutes);
//Think of this line of code like defining a middleware which will intercept all request starting with '/'
```

Consequenlty, when you go to localhost:9000, you are redirected to this router.

As we can see here :

```
apiRouter.get('/', function (req, res, next){
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: './public/html'})
});
```

For a request '/', it will send the file index.html. That's great !

Now, let's take a look at yout index.html file :

```
<main>
  <div> all the stuff </div>
</main>
```

It is just a template, not the real html page you need.

AngularJS in a single page app MVC, consequently, what you need to do is :

- Having one 'real' html page with all the dependecies and stuff etc. This page is calling your ui-router.
- Having small templates html files which are rendered depending on the ui-router state.

Here shell.html seems to be your 'real' html file which call the dependancies and the ui-router which will make you able to navigate through your states.

Of course, in a more complex structure, what I said is totally wrong. You can have more complex files to lazy load some libraries but I think this is not first priority for you.

I tried to explain it the simpliest way possible, hope it will help and good luck shaping up with MEAN.